# filetype for numbers separated by whitespace?

Tags: text, file-type

I am thinking of using a filetype of numbers (as text) separated by whitespace in one of my apps.  Any kind of whitespace (space, line break, whatever) will do.  I am curious if this is a standard file type?  If so, what is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programs seem to implement it as `txt`, and for a simple enough format, I think that would be fine.

If your intention is to allow access to the file from excel or ilk, I would reccomend using Tab characters (`\t` or `0x0b`) to separate fields with newlines separating records.  Name it either .tsv or .txt and you have [Tab Separated Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values).